# How do I create a fragment for a Gatsby StaticQuery Hook?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to create a fragment for a StaticQuery hook in Gatsby JS, but I am unsure as to how to create it. I tried creating another fragment variable like so:

```
const fixedImage = graphql`
    fragment fixedImage on File {
        childImageSharp{
            fixed{
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
        }
    }
    `
```

But my query still couldn't find the fragment, I also tried passing it as an argument as seen below, but to no avail.

```
const data = ({fixedImage}) => useStaticQuery(graphql`
query MyQuery {
  square1: file{
    ...fixedImage
  }
  square2: file{
    ...fixedImage
  }
  square3: file{
    ...fixedImage
  }
  square4: file{
    ...fixedImage
  }
}
`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the fragment query in a component. It doesn't matter which component but it's good practice to export it in a related component ( ie. Image.jsx).

**Image.jsx:**

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Image from "gatsby-image"

export default ({ image }) => (
  <div>
    <Image fixed={image.childImageSharp.fixed} />
  </div>
)
export const query = graphql`
  fragment fixedImage on File {
        childImageSharp{
            fixed{
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
        }
    }
`
```

Then you can use the fragment in other components.

**Post.jsx:**

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Image from "./Image.jsx"

export default () => {
const data = useStaticQuery(query)
const { square1 } = data

 return (
   <div>
     <Image image={square1} />
   </div>
  )
}

const query = graphql`
    query MyQuery {
        square1: file(absolutePath: { regex: "/square1.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)/" }) {
            ...fixedImage
        }
    }
`
```

More info on fragments in Gatsby: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-graphql-fragments/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Gatsby Image; I wanted to cut down the repetition in calling childImageSharp each time. 
I resolved it by creating the fragment inline before the query like this:

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    fragment fluidImage on File {
        childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
        }
    }
    query {
      imageOne: file(relativePath: { eq: "img/image1.jpg" }) {
        ...fluidImage
      }
      imageTwo: file(relativePath: { eq: "img/image2.jpg" }) {
        ...fluidImage
      }
      imageThree: file(relativePath: { eq: "img/image3.jpg" }) {
        ...fluidImage
      }
    }
  `);
```